# Aggregate data to weekly level with every week starting from Monday

Tags: r, time-series, aggregate-functions

I have a data frame like,

```
2015-01-30     1       Fri
2015-01-30     2       Sat
2015-02-01     3       Sun
2015-02-02     1       Mon
2015-02-03     1       Tue
2015-02-04     1       Wed 
2015-02-05     1       Thu
2015-02-06     1       Fri
2015-02-07     1       Sat
2015-02-08     1       Sun
```

I want to aggregaate it to weekly level such that every week starts from "monday" and ends in "sunday". So, in the aggregated data for above, first week should end on 2015-02-01.

output should look like something for above

```
firstweek    6  
secondweek   7
```

I tried this,

```
data <- as.xts(data$value,order.by=as.Date(data$interval))
weekly <- apply.weekly(data,sum)
```

But here in the final result, every week is starting from Sunday.

Comment: Maybe `aggregate(V2 ~ cumsum(V3 == "Mon"), df, sum)`?

Comment: This link may help you as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944838/forcing-full-weeks-with-apply-weekly

Comment: Check `strptime`; `%V` weeks start on mondays.

Answer (score 2):

This should work. I've called the dataframe `m` and named the columns possibly different to yours.

```
library(plyr) # install.packages("plyr")

colnames(m) = c("Date", "count","Day")
start  = as.Date("2015-01-26")
m$Week <- floor(unclass(as.Date(m$Date) - as.Date(start)) / 7) + 1
m$Week = as.numeric(m$Week)
m %>% group_by(Week) %>% summarise(count = sum(count))
```

The library plyr is great for data manipulation, but it's just a rough hack to get the week number in.

Answer (score 2):

Convert to date and use the `%W` format to get a week number...

```
df <- read.csv(textConnection("2015-01-30,     1,       Fri,
2015-01-30,     2,       Sat,
2015-02-01,     3,       Sun,
2015-02-02,     1,       Mon,
2015-02-03,     1,       Tue,
2015-02-04,     1,       Wed,
2015-02-05,     1,       Thu,
2015-02-06,     1,       Fri,
2015-02-07,     1,       Sat,
2015-02-08,     1,       Sun"), header=F, stringsAsFactors=F)
names(df) <- c("date", "something", "day")
df$date <- as.Date(df$date, format="%Y-%m-%d")
df$week <- format(df$date, "%W")
aggregate(df$something, list(df$week), sum)
```

Comment: Just noticed you want the week to start on Monday. I think if you add a day to the date.... `df$week <- format(df$date + 1, "%W")`, it will get you there.

Answer (score 2):

Wit `dplyr` and `lubridate` is this really easy thanks to the function `isoweek`

```
my.df <- read.table(header=FALSE, text=
  '2015-01-30     1       Fri
   2015-01-30     2       Sat
   2015-02-01     3       Sun
   2015-02-02     1       Mon
   2015-02-03     1       Tue
   2015-02-04     1       Wed 
   2015-02-05     1       Thu
   2015-02-06     1       Fri
   2015-02-07     1       Sat
   2015-02-08     1       Sun')
 my.df %>% mutate(week = isoweek(V1)) %>% group_by(week) %>% summarise(sum(V2))
```

or a bit shorter

```
my.df %>% group_by(isoweek(V1)) %>% summarise(sum(V2))
```